# PHP page is not shown on browser rather it gets downloaded

Tags: php, ubuntu

When I try to visit a PHP page rather showing the contents the browser starts downloading the page. I am using ubuntu and I have installed PHP5 on it.

Comment: which server you are using or didn't installed any server like Apache?

Comment: We are not able to stand behind you and point out what you should do. In order to help we need to know *a lot more* about your setup and what you have tried so far.

Comment: You have not correctly configured your server for PHP.

Comment: Hi, Welcome To stackoverflow.com please improve your question and provide more information.

Comment: Yes, I have installed apache, mysql and php. 
Actually I was trying to set up froxlor on my machine. I did the same things on a different ubuntu machine the previous day and everything was ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - please double check

http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

The most possible is that you forget

```
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
```

or

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```